# Как увеличить размер шрифта (размер консоли) в Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Всем привет

Спасибо тем, кто ответит.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Там внизу консоли есть проценты:
[image: карт]

Comment: Скриншот с мобилки из видео? сильно, но до скриншота в ворде в архиве еще чуть чуть не дотягивает =)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ........ У меня немного Другая консоль.... Почему-то.

Comment: это вроде даже не размер консоли, а размер текста именно в IDE

Comment: Pekor, - можно чуть-чуть Подробнее?....

Comment: тебе где надо увеличить размер текста - в консоли при запуске программы или в текстовом редакторе IDE?

Comment: Мне надо увеличить размер шрифта при наборе в Visual Studio. Пока не знаю как объяснить по-другому.

Comment: Т.е. в гугловской консоли я просто нажимаю Ctrl + , а здесь это не работает.......